# Angular ternary expression that runs more than one line of code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ternary-operator

so I have this example of code,
in one of my forms, it works perfectly.

```
ng-submit="
    commentCtrl.edit(comment.id, comment.text);
    comment.edit=false;
"
```

on the other hand, when I try to run multiple "commands" in a ternary ng-keyup, things go wrong, angular can't parse it.

```
ng-keyup="
($event.keyCode == 13 && !$event.shiftKey)
?
commentCtrl.edit(comment.id, comment.text);comment.edit=false
:
return"
```

also tried:

```
($event.keyCode == 13 && !$event.shiftKey)
?
commentCtrl.edit(comment.id, comment.text) && comment.edit=false
:
return"
```

help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad practice to write such expressions inside of markup.

Anyway you can do it by putting the values into an array:

```
ng-submit="[commentCtrl.edit(comment.id, comment.text), comment.edit=false]"

ng-keyup="($event.keyCode == 13 && !$event.shiftKey)
? [commentCtrl.edit(comment.id, comment.text), comment.edit=false]
: 0"
```

Comment: is it possible to preventDefault the keypress with ng-keyup? I tried using this array: [$event.preventDefault, commentCtrl.edit(comment.id, comment.text), comment.edit=false]

Comment: @GuyMazuz, `$event.preventDefault` - you've just read the function, but haven't call it. Try `$event.preventDefault()` instead.

Comment: you're probably right, but it's not working either way :( for the same reason alert('123') isn't working I guess, maybe if i set it to true? like this: $event.preventDefault=true

Comment: @GuyMazuz, I need more code to unswer. Please ask another question with minimal code example and problem description. Then invite me there using comments.