# More than one function in ng-click directory using ternary operator

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to use ternary operator in ng-click directory and call more than one function? I mean something like that:

```
<div ng-click="a==1 ? func1() func2() : ''">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but see the ternary operator, as this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#Description) says:

> You can also do more than one single operation per case, separating
> them with a comma, and enclosing them in parenthesis:

```
var stop = false, age = 23;

age > 18 ? (
    alert('OK, you can go.'),
    location.assign('continue.html') ) : (
    stop = true,
    alert('Sorry, you are much too young!') );
```

> You can also do more than one operation during the assignation of a
> value. In this case, the last comma-separated value of the parenthesis
> will be the value to be assigned.

But, it's not a problem for you.

Comment: It's a syntax error using `ng-click="a==1 ? ( func1(), func2() ) : ' '  "`

Comment: Mm see the answer of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476962/angular-ternary-expression-that-runs-more-than-one-line-of-code It's weird, but maybe the []?

Answer (score 0):

You can call functions via ternary operator.

```
(a == 1) ? function1() : function2();
(a == 1) ? function1(param1) : function2(param1); //with input params
```

But calling the one, as you posted will return syntax error. Try below;

```
(a == 1) ? (function1(),function2()) : "'";
(a == 1) ? (function() { function1(); function2() })() : "'";
```

Though it's possible, it's not clean & easily readable. My suggestion would be to try as below;

```
(a == 1) ? combinedFunction() : "'";  //Put function1 & function2 within this combined function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the functions in conditional operator

```
<div ng-click="a==1 ? func1(func2()) : angular.noop() ">
```

angular.noop() is an empty function or put "null"

plnkr like [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/b577k17rPgqAxTFT1e6z/)